# How to let the user pick certain positions in an array and write it to a file

Tags: java, arrays

I have been stuck for some time now. In my code, I want to read all of the names I have from a separate file, and I want to allow the user to select how many names they want to save to a new separate file and allow them to select which names they want to save to the file (by selecting the number in-front of the names printed to the screen).
I am not sure on how I would allow the user to select certain positions in the array "names" to print to a new file. My idea was to use the array "select" and check what number was in that array (eg select[0] = 1) and print out number[1].

Any help would be much appreciated, thankyou!

```
public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            BufferedWriter writefile;
            BufferedReader readfile;
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            readfile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("names.txt"));
            writefile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("nameChoices.txt"));
            String names[] = new String[10];
            System.out.println("Here are the list of names:");
            System.out.println();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                names[i] = readfile.readLine();
                System.out.println(i + ". " + names[i]);
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Please enter the number of names you want to select:");
            int choice = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter the number infront of the names you want to select: ");
            int select[] = new int[choice];
            for (int j = 0; j < choice; j++) {
                select[j] = scan.nextInt();
            }


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your Question:** "I am not sure on how I would allow the user to select certain positions in the array "names" to print to a new file."

There is nothing wrong with the way you have already opted to do this other than perhaps letting the User know what selection they happen to be currently on and trapping for invalid entries such as values too high or too low and of course alpha characters where numerical characters are required. Without taking care of this business you leave things open to specific Error Exceptions. When asking the User for input a good solution would be for you to take care of what can go wrong and if it does, allow the User to re-enter the required data.

The biggest problem you have is that you have no mechanism in place to write the desired data to file. You've started by declaring a **BufferedWriter** object but you have yet to implement it. This would of course entail iterating through the **select** array which ultimately each element holds the index of the names desired to save to file. Simply iterate through the **select** array and write each name to file:

```
for (int i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
    writefile.write(name[select[i]] + System.lineSeparator()); 
    writefile.flush();
}
// Close the file when all writing is done.
writefile.close();
```

With what is discussed above you might have a solution that would look something like this:

```
try {
    BufferedWriter writefile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("nameChoices.txt"));
    BufferedReader readfile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("names.txt"));
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);    

    String allNames = "", fileLine = "";
    while((fileLine = readfile.readLine()) != null) {
        // Using a 'Terary Operator' to fill the allNames variable
        // with a comma delimited string of all the names in file. It
        // doesn't matter how many names are in file.
        allNames+= (allNames.equals("")) ? fileLine : "," + fileLine;
    }
    // Split the string in allNames to the names array.
    String names[] = allNames.split(",");

    // Display the names in console:
    // Use the System.out.format() method
    // to create a columnar display.
    System.out.println("Here are the list of names:");
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        // Use the modulus operator to ensure 4 columns 
        if (i % 4 == 0){ 
            // Print a new line
            System.out.print("\n"); 
        }
        System.out.format("%-15s", (i+1) + ". " + names[i]);
    }
    readfile.close(); // Close the reader. Don't need to leave it open.
    System.out.println();

    // Get the number of names the User wants to save...
    int choice = 0;
    while (choice == 0) {
        System.out.println("\nPlease enter the number of names you want to select:");
        try {
            choice = scan.nextInt(); 
        } 
        catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.err.println("Invalid Entry! Numerical value Only!\n");
            scan.nextLine(); // Clear the scanner buffer
            choice = 0;
        }
    }

    // Get the actual names the User wants to save...
    System.out.println();
    int j = 0;
    int select[] = new int[choice];
    System.out.println("Enter the numbers in front of the names you want to select: ");
    while (j < choice) {
        System.out.println("Enter the number for name #" + (j+1) + ": ");
        try {
            int index = scan.nextInt();
            if (index < 1 || index > names.length) {
                throw new InputMismatchException();
            }
            select[j] = index;
            j++;
        } 
        catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.err.println("Invalid Entry! Numerical value Only (1 to " + 
                               names.length + ")!\n");
            scan.nextLine(); // Clear the scanner buffer
        }
    }

    //Write choices to file and Console...
    System.out.print("\nSaving Names: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
        String save = names[select[i]-1] ;
        System.out.print(save + "\t");
        writefile.write(save + System.lineSeparator());
        writefile.flush();
    }
    writefile.close(); // close the writer
    System.out.println("\nDONE! File Created!");
} 
catch (IOException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
```

In this example invalid entries are taken care of and the User is given the chance to enter valid data.